# alarm clock music problem

Tags: 12.04

I'm new to Ubuntu (currently using 12.04 LTS) and while using Alarm Clock and try to put music to wake me up, I get something like GStreamer is missing a plugin and this really bothers me... Anyway, An answer would be really appreciated ! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal emulator (Ctrl + Alt + T) and allow the *Multiverse* repository with the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) multiverse"
sudo apt-get update
```

And then you'll have to install `ubuntu-restricted-addons` and `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

For Ubuntu use the command:

```
sudo apt-get ubuntu-restricted-addons
sudo apt-get ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

For Kubuntu use:

```
sudo apt-get kubuntu-restricted-addons
sudo apt-get kubuntu-restricted-extras
```

For Lubuntu use:

```
sudo apt-get lubuntu-restricted-addons
sudo apt-get lubuntu-restricted-extras
```

For Xubuntu use:

```
sudo apt-get xubuntu-restricted-addons
sudo apt-get xubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 2):

I think "install" is missing in the argument list. It should read

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-addons
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```