# In alarm-clock-applet I try to play sound, I get this error: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in

Tags: 16.04, sound, gstreamer

[image: See the screenshot]

Sound works just fine on everything else but while trying to use the applet, it just doesn't work. I tried everything that I could find such as [alarm-clock-music-problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438331/alarm-clock-music-problem) and [gstreamer-installation-is-missing-a-plug-in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596184/gstreamer-installation-is-missing-a-plug-in) but that did not work. Does anyone know how to fix this?
I am running Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

(as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/456259/575262) and also [this one on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31768647/6281925)).

Otherwise, can you add the output of `gst-launch -m`?

Comment: I actually just downgraded from 18.04 to 16.04 and it works fine. But thanks anyway.